# data are not transmitted in the listview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

i have two xml files. If you select from the drop-down list , the data from the XML file , were moved into the table. But only work first xml file when I click on a second , then nothing happens , the table is not filled.Where is my mistake?

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem lv = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            textBox1.Text = lv.SubItems[1].Text;
            textBox2.Text = lv.SubItems[2].Text;
            textBox3.Text = lv.SubItems[3].Text;

        }

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ds.ReadXml(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (DataRow Dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i]["group"].ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i]["document"].ToString());
                    i++;
                    listView1.Items.Add(lv);


                }
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                ds1.ReadXml(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");
                dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
                if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow qw in dt1.Rows)
                    {
                        ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dt1.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
                        lv.SubItems.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
                        lv.SubItems.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["group"].ToString());
                        lv.SubItems.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["document"].ToString());
                        i++;
                        listView1.Items.Add(lv);


                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with the code.  The ListView isn't recognizing that any change occurred to the control so the control isn't refreshed.  Usually clearing  the rows before filling will help.  The clear method calls the control paint method which will refresh the control, then adding new data will work probably.

Comment: But if I just select the second file that would fill in the table , it will be empty. Fill in the table should the first or second xml file

Comment: What happens if you only add the 2nd xml file to the ListView without adding first file?

Answer (score 0):

You have exact same file for both comboBox1 options:
`ds.ReadXml(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");`. I assume the `@"C:\XMLFile1.xml"` has to be different for the second file.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //Opening bracket 1
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0) //Option 1
    { //Opening bracket 2

        ds.ReadXml(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");  //<<====================== File1
        dt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {//Opening bracket 3
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow Dr in dt.Rows)
            {//Opening bracket 4
                ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i]["group"].ToString());
                lv.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i]["document"].ToString());
                i++;
                listView1.Items.Add(lv);


            }//Closing bracket 4
        }//Opening bracket 3
    }//Closing Bracket 2
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)  //Option 2
    {
         DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
         DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
         ds1.ReadXml(@"C:\XMLFile1.xml");     //<<====================== still File1
         dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
         if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             int i = 0;
             foreach (DataRow qw in dt1.Rows)
             {
                 ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dt1.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
                 lv.SubItems.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString());
                 lv.SubItems.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["group"].ToString());
                 lv.SubItems.Add(dt1.Rows[i]["document"].ToString());
                 i++;
                 listView1.Items.Add(lv);



            }
        }
    }
}//Closing Bracket 1
```

Edit:

1. Count your opening and closing brackets
2. You're only adding to list view `listView1.Items.Add(lv)`. Unless you delete old entries, new ones will appear on the bottom of the list or mixed in.

Comment: Oh its my fails. Program does not work properly , even if correct this problem

Comment: Look at my answer again, You were missing Closing bracket 2 (bracked for first `if` statement block, which mean your `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)` was inside `if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)` block, which means it could never be executed